# Telemetry system for garden sensors

Tags: sensors

I apologize if this isn't the right place for this post. Essentially, I'm trying to find a (relatively) low-cost solution for how to take data from a water content and conductivity sensor (specifically this: https://www.metergroup.com/en/meter-environment/products/teros-12-soil-moisture-sensor) and display/view it on a remote device (i.e. phone, PC, etc.)

Currently, the only way to view the data from the sensor is to be physically near it via Bluetooth and using their app. If you want to view the data remotely (outside of Bluetooth range) METER Group requires that you buy their whole platform, which is $3,600/year for access in addition to $3,500 for the equipment to do so.

Does anyone know of a system where I could plug their device in and be able to access the water content, temperature, and conductivity data?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the answer per se, however seems it's doable.

Their manual (https://library.metergroup.com/Manuals/18225_TEROS11-12_%20Pages.pdf) states it's using SDI-12 protocol. The protocol is described in [integrator guide](https://library.metergroup.com/Integrator%20Guide/18224%20TEROS%2011-12%20Integrator%20Guide.pdf). What's more important, there is an Arduino library: https://github.com/EnviroDIY/Arduino-SDI-12 which (probably) can be used with this sensor. Having it paired with any microcontroller you are able to collect/reprocess the data.
The simplest solution might be to read the sensor data by arduino and send it over the internet (or GPRS) to your own server for storage/processing/display.

Hope it helps.